# ul div is pushing out of parent

Tags: css, html-lists, inline-styles

I have an issue with a ul div. My parent div for the ul is not holding it in. I have the parent div (subMenu) positioned and z-indexed but the ul child (subMen) just pushes out and shows up on bottom of it, when it should be contained within the parent and pulled up to the positioning I applied to the parent. I've tried floating and list-style positioning it. But nothing seems to matter. Here is the CSS code:

```
#subMenu {
background-image: url(images/sub_nav_background2.png);
width: 1280px;
height: 60px;
position: relative;
top: -145px;
z-index: -100;
}

#subMen {
margin-left: 330px;
list-style-position: inside !important;
float: left !important;
height: 20px;
width: 900px !important;
font-size: 14px;

}
```

Here is the HTML section involving this.

```
<div id="subMenu">
        <ul id="subMen">
        <li><a href="#">BRAND MARKETING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">EXPERIENTIAL MARKETING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PERFORMANCE SOLUTIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MEETING & EVENT SOLUTIONS</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

And here is the [IMAGE](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v88/Nesso/ScreenShot2013-03-11at111827AM_zpsbd04c279.png) of what is going on.

The listed menu at the bottom there should be in that grey area and tucked under the main nav at the top.

Comment: Please provide the link,I will try to figure out for you

Comment: a bit of html would also help

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
list-style-position:inside;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you float something it can escape its parent div. You should add the `overflow` property to your parent. If you specify `overflow: hidden` it will the hide the overflow; `overflow: scroll` will scroll.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BZFTY/2/.

In the above fiddle, try changing the overflow property to different values: `default`, `scroll`, and `hidden`.

Comment: I'm using php and wordpress so I can't show a live example but I can show the html

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a fiddle based on your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/wby6W/1/

```
#subMenu {
background:#ccc;
width: 1280px;
height: 60px;
position: relative;
z-index: -100;
overflow:hidden;
}

#subMen {
margin-left: 330px;
float: left;
width: 900px;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

I've removed the top:-145px because I needed to see the text within the window.
I've also added overflow:hidden to your CSS as suggested above.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out for myself. For some reason I need to position based on negative margin. If I used the regular positioning it didn't effect the ul div. Thanks for the help everyone! You guys made it easier to pinpoint the issues I need to change. The fiddle definitely helped!